# UE5 Very poor performance of Memcpy

Tags: c++, ros, unreal-engine5

I'm currently working on publishing images generated in Unreal to ROS, but now I'm facing strange performance issues.

I'm using Unreal 5.2 on Ubuntu 20, with a Ryzen 5 5600X, a RTX 3070 and 40GB of RAM.

My method currently looks like this

```cpp
void FROSOutputServer::PublishImage(ros::Publisher& ImagePublisher, TSharedPtr<FSensorDataBase>& SensorData){ 
   
    TRACE_CPUPROFILER_EVENT_SCOPE(FROSOuputServer::PublishImage);
    FCameraData* CameraData = static_cast<FCameraData*>(SensorData.Get());
    
    sensor_msgs::ImagePtr ImgMsgPtr = boost::make_shared<sensor_msgs::Image>();

    ros::Time TimeStamp;
    TimeStamp.fromSec(CameraData->Timestamp.ToDouble());
    ImgMsgPtr->header.stamp = TimeStamp;
    ImgMsgPtr->header.frame_id = "test";
    ImgMsgPtr->step = CameraData->Width * 3; 
    ImgMsgPtr->height = CameraData->Height;
    ImgMsgPtr->width = CameraData->Width;
    ImgMsgPtr->encoding = "bgr8";
    ImgMsgPtr->is_bigendian = 0;
    
    {
        TRACE_CPUPROFILER_EVENT_SCOPE(FROSOuputServer::PublishImage::Copy);
        ImgMsgPtr->data.resize(CameraData->ImageData.Num());
        uint8* DestPtr = ImgMsgPtr->data.data();
        uint8* SrcPtr = CameraData->ImageData.GetData();
        FMemory::Memcpy(DestPtr, SrcPtr, CameraData->ImageData.Num());
    }
    {
        TRACE_CPUPROFILER_EVENT_SCOPE(FROSOuputServer::PublishImage::Publish);
        ImagePublisher.publish(ImgMsgPtr);
    }

    // Only for debugging purposes, this would be called implicitly by the shared pointer destructor
    {
        TRACE_CPUPROFILER_EVENT_SCOPE(FROSOuputServer::PublishImage::FreeUnrealPtr);
        SensorData.Reset();
    }

    {
        TRACE_CPUPROFILER_EVENT_SCOPE(FROSOuputServer::PublishImage::FreeBoostPtr);
        ImgMsgPtr.reset();
    }
}
```

With these Unreal data structs:

```cpp
struct FSensorDataBase
{
    Utils::Time Timestamp;
};
struct FCameraData : public FSensorDataBase
{
    
    TArray<uint8> ImageData;
    uint32 Width;
    uint32 Height;
};
```

For testing purposes, I created a 1000x1000 image, resulting in a 3MB TArray.

I expected modern CPUs to take very little time to copy such "small" amounts of data, but when profiling I encountered very poor results.
I used Unreal Insights for profiling. (See TRACE_CPUPROFILER_EVENT_SCOPE macro above)
[image: Unreal Insights Screenshot]
So the copy operation takes about 13.5ms and freeing the boost pointer after it is published takes another 20.8ms . Unreals shared pointer isn't freed in this scope.

Is there anyway to optimize this or am I simply running into CPU constraints due to Unreals overhead?

Comment: Any questions concerning the speed of C++ must be accompanied by the compiler options used, especially the optimization settings used to build the program.

Comment: You should aslo profile `ImgMsgPtr->data.resize(CameraData->ImageData.Num());` seperately from memcpy. As well was dtor for `sensor_msgs::Image`